# How to create a dict equivalent in Python from Perl hash?

Tags: python, perl, hash

I'm new to python, and can't get my head around dict hashes.

Here's my perl code:

```
my %sites;

foreach (@indexes) {
       push @{$sites{$1}}, $_ if (/.*\.(.*)/);
}

foreach my $sites (keys %sites)
{
        @devices = @{$sites{$sites}};
        #Do stuff
```

How do I do the same in Python?

Comment: can you describe what you're trying to do, my perl is rusty.

Comment: @monkut: something like take an array of filenames and group them by extension, then process them one extension at a time

Comment: @ysth: thats exactly right. grouping similar files together, and then running some comparisons on the similar files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty direct translation:

```
import re

re_domain = re.compile(".*\.(.*)")
sites = {}

for index in indexes:
    match = re_domain.search(index)
    if match:
        sites.setdefault(match.group(1), []).append(index)

for site_key in sites.keys():
    devices = sites[site_key]
```

A more Pythonic way would be to do it like this:

```
import collections
import os.path

sites = collections.defaultdict(list)

for index in indexes:
    root, ext = os.path.splitext(index)
    sites[ext].append(index)

for site_key, devices in sites.iteritems():
    ...
```

Comment: Isn't the terminating "/" in the pattern a residue of Perl's delimiter?

Comment: Very neat trick, this `dict.get()`. I suppose there's always something to discover... So far I always painfully coded around default values for `dict` entries ;-)

Comment: `.get()` **returns** the default value--it doesn't **update** the dictionary. You'd need to add `sites[match.group(1)] = ` to the beginning of that line to get the desired behavior. Also, if the line doesn't math, then `match.group(1)` will give you an `AttributeError`, so you should put an `if match:` before that line.

Comment: That said, the "more Pythonic" solution is much better anyway.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks heaps - the "more Pythonic" solution works brilliantly.

Comment: Fixed direct translation version after comments of Kyle Strand for completeness.